# Problems with Relative layout

Tags: android

I am trying to place two components. The first one (Edittext) should expand till the next component (a submit Button). How do I do this? My XML is as follows...
The problem is that the Edittext expands to fill the screen and hides the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/etFeedBackText"
            android:hint="What do you think of this app? Any comments or suggestions?"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/btnFeedBackSubmit"              
            >       
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFeedBackSubmit"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/etFeedBackText"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the Button declaration above the EditText, and set in EditText property :
`android:layout_above="@id/btnFeedBackSubmit"`

Answer (score 0):

remove this line

```
 android:layout_alignBottom="@id/btnFeedBackSubmit"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/etFeedBackText"
            android:hint="What do you think of this app? Any comments or suggestions?"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/btnFeedBackSubmit"              
            >       
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFeedBackSubmit"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/etFeedBackText"
            android:hint="What do you think of this app? Any comments or suggestions?"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     XXXXXXXX remove this      android:layout_alignBottom="@id/btnFeedBackSubmit"   
     XXXXXXXX write this       android:layout_above="@id/btnFeedBackSubmit"           
            >       
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFeedBackSubmit"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/etFeedBackText"
     android:hint="What do you think of this app? Any comments or suggestions?"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_above="@id/btnFeedBackSubmit" />       
</RelativeLayout>
```